# В разных enum нельзя применять одинаковые имена

Tags: c++

Есть два `enum`: `enum OBJECT_PULSES` и `enum OBJECT_SENSOR_MODE_RD` имена в перечислениях одинаковые `RD_CH...`, но их числовые значения разные. При компиляции ошибка: *redeclaration*. Это особенность языка или что не так с настройками компилятора, как это побороть кроме как переименования?

```
enum OBJECT_PULSES
{
    RD_CH1  = 14, // Счетчик импульсов, канал 1
    // ...
    RD_CH32 = 45 // Счетчик импульсов, канал 32
};

enum OBJECT_SENSOR_MODE_RD
{
    RD_CH1  = 46, //  RD. Режим датчика, канал 1
    // ...
    RD_CH32 = 77, //  RD. Режим датчика, канал 32
};
```

Comment: Отвык я от плюсов, но глядя на такое количество строк копипасты у меня возникает законный вопрос -- а нельзя ли это как-то красиво отрефакторить? Явно видно, что есть два режима ("счётчик импульсов" и "режим датчика"), есть 32 канала, которые нумеруются от 14 или от до 32 + 14.

Comment: @AK , Вы автору вопроса предлагаете в режиме датчика каждый раз сдвиг 32 плюсовать? Это гораздо хуже копипасты. Хотя бы потому, что множества закрывают внутреннюю реализацию режимов и каналов. Когда в коде упоминается такой-то канал в таком-то режиме не важно, какое число ему соответствует, это уже другой уровень абстракции. А в небольшом количестве копипасты ничего страшного нет - убрал в отдельный файлик - она и не мешает. Зато никаких "магических чисел" по остальному коду.

Comment: @YuryPlinto почему плюс 32 хуже копипасты, если обернуть этот 32 в тот же enum?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Константы enum'ов не имеют собственной области видимости, поэтому у приведённых двух енумов всё оказывается в одной области видимости. Естественно, в одной области видимости одинаковые имена недопустимы.

Как вариант, можно использовать [`enum class`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554524/178988), которые создают свой скоуп.
Либо использовать более старую идею с обёртыванием enum'а в пространство имён.